getting Pytorch activation function from .pth model
I am looking for a method to retrieve the activation functions used in a PyTorch network saved as a .pth file (torch.save(model)). Indeed, if the activation functions were not declared in the class when creating the model but only in the forward method, I am unable to identify these activation functions
eg:

class SimpleCNN_2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SimpleCNN_2, self).__init__()

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=16, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=16, out_channels=32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(in_features=32768, out_features=128)  
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(in_features=128, out_features=10)  

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.conv2(x))
        x = nn.Flatten()(x)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

I get this description:
SimpleCNN_2(
  (conv1): Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
  (conv2): Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=(3, 3), stride=(1, 1), padding=(1, 1))
  (fc1): Linear(in_features=32768, out_features=128, bias=True)
  (fc2): Linear(in_features=128, out_features=10, bias=True)
)

If activation function are declared, I don't have any issue. My concern is about the fact that I want to assess a network from a .pth file, and if I can't get the whole structure of the network it's a mess.
I would like to have a method that allows me to obtain the complete structure of a network, layer by layer, from a .pth file, in the form of a list, without knowing the structure of the network in advance.

I think the problem is that the activation function does not have any parameter that is serialized, so you will not find it in the pth file. Usually in pytorch you need the model you will need the model definition to get everything. One workaround might be to use a Sequential. I guess that should store the activation functions too.
Here's an example on how to save/reload
# To save
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'out.pth')
# To reload
model = SimpleCNN_2()
model3.load_state_dict(torch.load('out.pth'))


The model saved using the 'torch.save' method contains the forward method. Indeed, if I apply
forward_method = model.forward
source_code = inspect.getsource(forward_method)
print(source_code)

I get the forward method. I would like to avoid using a parser to reconstruct the forward method. I need to override this method layer by layer, activation function by activation function, to automatically analyze my network.

Your last comment is not really clear to me. You do not need a parser to reconstruct your forward method, but you cannot serialize the model definition AFAIK. You need the parameters. I edited my answer to be clearer.
